# vuforia doesn't accept old script for AR unity app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

my friend has created a code for me to create an AR app using vuforia in unity which was working completely ok.
now I install new unity with the new version of vuforia it shows some error
I find out some changes were applied like "MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler" is changed to "DefaultTrackableEventHandler"
but I have some error which cant understand :

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class Shutter0 : DefaultTrackableEventHandler
{
TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
GameObject derakht;
string IP;
public int port;
GameObject TextMesh;
public string myText;
// "connection" things
IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
UdpClient client;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    derakht = GameObject.Find("derakht");
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
    //OnTrackingLost();
    IP = "127.0.0.1";
    port = 8050;
    string myText = "25j";
    remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
    client = new UdpClient();
    // status
    print("Sending to " + IP + " : " + port);
}
// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
// tracking state changes.
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
 TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
 TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();
    }

}

private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    try
    {
        // encode string to UTF8-coded bytes
        myText = "0";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myText);
        // send the data
        client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        print(err.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This post https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/registertrackableeventhandler-outdated discusses repacing the depricated RegisterTrackableEventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be quite self-explanatory

> `TrackableBehaviour` does not contain a definition for `RegisterTrackableEventHandler`

This method simply doesn't exist (anymore).

---

you probably rather mean [`RegisterOnTrackableStatusChanged`](https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1TrackableBehaviour.html#a89c5cc5021e53a2dc83eb4a1f5963f6e) like

```
mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterOnTrackableStatusChanged(OnTrackableStateChanged);
```

---

Btw I wouldn't inherit from that `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` tbh .. it's kind of shitty ^^

I would rather implement my own like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(TrackableBehaviour))]
public class TrackableEventHandlerEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TrackableBehaviour _trackableBehaviour;

    public UnityEvent onTrackingFound;
    public UnityEvent onTrackingLost;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_trackableBehaviour) _trackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();

        if(!_trackableBehaviour)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"This component requires a {nameof(TrackableBehaviour)} !", this);
            return;
        }

        _trackableBehaviour.RegisterOnTrackableStatusChanged(OnTrackableStateChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called when the tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        switch(newStatus)
        { 
            case TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED:
            case TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED:
            case TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED:
                OnTrackingFound();
                break;
        
            default:
                OnTrackingLost();
                break;
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        Debug.Log("Trackable " + _trackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
        onTrackingFound.Invoke();
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        Debug.Log("Trackable " + _trackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
        onTrackingLost.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Why? → Because this way you

- can let any other method listen to these two [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html)s by either adding callbacks via the Inspector (like in button `onClick`) or via code using e.g.

  ```
   _trackableEventHandlerEvents.onTrackingLost.AddCallback(() => Debug.Log("Hello World!"));
  ```
- you can simply extend the methods directly by inheriting from that component and extend e.g.

  ```
  protected override void OnTrackingFound()
  {
      // You can keep the default behavior
      // or if you remove this line you can completely overwrite the behavior
      base.OnTrackingFound();

      // Additional behavior
  }
  ```